# is it possible to change notification icon dynamically

Tags: ios, push-notification, icons, uilocalnotification

I would like to change notification icon from time to time.

As far as I have searched its not possible.

iOS by default takes an image that 29 by 29 or 58 by 58 or smallest image available in app icons.

We don't have any control over it.

Thanks,

Raju Bhai

Comment: I'm wondering which you want change,the app icon or the icon badge.

Comment: icon that appears in the notification the small icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible because the icon is chosen from the **app bundle**'s app *icon list* and *app bundle is created while compiling the project* so you can't do anything but in *android you can* do it.

Comment: Can you give some reference for it ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/NotificationCenter.html

Comment: Is it possible to be multiple images in binary with other name and push notification body will revel the icon name?

Answer (score 4):

As you have searched,you can't change it by yourself.This is because Apple don't permit copying others's logo.

Comment: I don't intend to use others logo...my logo but with different alpha settings

Comment: @RajuBhaiRocker I'm afraid you can't do that.